# Is it better to use a global variable or a namespace variable in tcl?

Tags: namespaces, tcl, tk-toolkit

I'm working on a Tcl-Tk project and have some namespaces. But the main part (the one for the main window and settings, which affect the whole program) is at the moment in the global namespace. I'm now wondering what is the best way for variables in the global namespace:

```
proc TestVariable {} {
    global MyVar
    variable MyVar
    ...
}
```

When `TestVariable` is in global namespace, both variants would achieve the same result. Am I correct? If this is the case, which variant is the better one to use?

Comment: `global` defines global variable, `variable` defines current namespace variable. Mixin them is not good idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Global variables are namespace variables in the global namespace. The global namespace is slightly special, in that it is where things appear from by default in other namespaces; this is what you want with commands (and what you ***REALLY*** don't want with variables, which is why you should declare namespace variables with the `variable` command).

In general, it's best to keep the global namespace for things that belong to the application overall, and put anything with more restricted applicability in some other namespace. If you're writing library code, *absolutely* put it in a namespace (often with the same name as the library package). That prevents much confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You should restrict yourself to use large number of global variables. It is always a good idea to use namespace for defining the variables.

Check "http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl13.html". This will provide you some insight and also check "http://tcl.tk/man/tcl8.5/tutorial/Tcl31.html" for more details